# Python inner function not printing the value that was initialised in the outer function

Tags: python, python-3.x, closures

In the following piece of code, 'message' variable printed the correct value in P1, but doesn't print anything in P2. I followed a tutorial for writing this piece of code, and it looks very similar to what he'd written. I'm using Python 3.6. Can someone explain why?

```
def outer_function(msg):
    message = msg 
    print(message) #P1
def inner_function():
    print(message) #P2
    return inner_function()
```

[Screen grab of the exact code in tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdzG8.png)

Comment: Indentation is important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes as mentioned by @see... apart form indentation , your code will cause Stack Overflow:

Maybe your code should look as below:

```
def outer_function(msg):
    message = msg
    print(message) #P1
    def inner_function():
        print(message) #P2
    return inner_function()
outer_function("hello")
```

Comment: Sorry, indentation was a typo. I also thought about that, but when I debugged the code. The was no call stack in vs code. Moreover, it printed the value for the person taking the tutorial.

Comment: Are you sure ? Can you give a link to that tutorial ?

Comment: Ur screengrab is somwhow matching on what i posted

Comment: @Rehan Azher 's answer is exactly what we can see in that tutorial

Comment: This should be marked as the answer @VishwanathSeshagiri

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the incorrect indentation (which I assume is a typo) your `inner_function` recursively calls itself forever, so I would expect a stack overflow here.

Comment: Sorry, indentation was a typo. I also thought about that, but when I debugged the code, there was no call stack in vs code. Moreover, it printed the value for the person taking the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Typically closures are simply the ability inner function to remember the variables of outer function even when the outer function goes out of scope.

So I would expect your code to
properly indented to work like it is supposed to be.

```
def outer_function(msg): 
      message = msg print(message) #P1 
      def inner_function():
            print(message) #P2 
      return inner_function()
```

Here, variable message is remembered by inner function even when outer_function goes out of scope

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
class A:
    message = None

    def outer_function(self, msg):
        self.message = msg
        print(self.message) #P1

    def inner_function(self):
        print(self.message) #P2
```

And then in your python shell:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.inner_function()
None
>>> a.outer_function('Hello!')
Hello!
>>> a.inner_function()
Hello!
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it'll work well, but I want to know why the inner function wasn't printing anything when it printed the message in the tutorial video.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't makes sense @VishwanathSeshagiri. It will crash if you call inner_function. Is that really the code you have?

Comment: @VishwanathSeshagiri maybe you wanted to call an outer_function INSIDE of your inner_function ?

Comment: @seesharper yes, sir. I've attached screen grab of the code in the video that I followed.

Comment: Look at the indentation @VishwanathSeshagiri! It is semantically significant in Python. Your code is indented completely differently.